# Session persists error in JMeter authenticate request

Tags: authentication, jmeter

In my jmeter web recording, I have an api/authenticate part which generates the token which has to be used
in subsequent requests. I did the part of correlation too. But the problem I face now is, the api/authenticate throws a session still persists error after sometime. In my script I have log out option too. In api/authenticate I am providing username and password in the headers. Since the session exists error is there, I can't get the token in the response body. Is it something that developers can fix for us? can you please help me with this? Or is there any request which is missing above this authentication part which jmeter didn't capture? I have authentication header manager added to my test plan to clear
authorization every iteration. Also cookie manager and cache manager. Nothing clears the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For well-behaved application "log out" request should clean the session, if it doesn't - you need to report it to your application developers.

Also check the token response, it might be the case it has some [time to live](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live) and if this is the case the token persistence could be a part of your application functionality so if there is a username/password combination associated with the token you should be using it until it expires before getting the new one. So you can write the token and its expiration date into a CSV file using [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin/) and use [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) to check whether the token is still active or not

Comment: This was indeed a confirmation I needed. What I did was, I found out that the token persistence was for about 4-5 hours for our application. After the allotted time, I generated a new token, correlated and ran in logout script. Then the next time I could run with same username/pw combo. Now the issue is solved. Thanks!